# AngularJS Columns col-md size

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I have 3 columns :

```
<div class="col-md-2">
<!-- Stuff 1 -->
</div>

<div class="col-md-6">
   <canvas id="canvasBlocs" width="950" height="1700"></canvas>   
</div>

<div class="col-md-4">
<!-- Stuff 3 -->
</div>
```

In my canvas, I have an image but it doesn't fit with the column (to big on the right and on the left if I zoom/de-zoom).

How I can make sure the canvas will be not bigger than the column?

I just want the canvas fits perfectly with the column.

**[EDIT]** my JS code. The image is now "to big" inside the canvas. How to scale the right size of the image in the canvas?

```
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvasBlocs');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = ".img/myImage.png;
    img.onload = function () {
       var pattern = context.createPattern(img, "no-repeat");
       context.fillStyle = pattern;
       context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    }
```

[EDIT2]

Canvas OK but image inside to big:
http://hpics.li/3cf3e2c

When I dezoom:
http://hpics.li/0a0230e

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just tell the canvas element to not expand wider then width of the parent container and it will scale proportionally:

```css
#canvasBlocs {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

To render the image in your case it's better to use drawImage method:

```
img.onload = function() {
   context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the canvas is now OK but I still have a problem with the image inside the canvas. It is like a big zoom now.

Comment: I am doing in my canvas something like var img = new Image();

                    img.onload = function () {}

Comment: What do you mean "big zoom"?

Comment: The image doesn't fit in the canvas. I just can see a little part of the image like if you zoom on it.

Comment: Of course. It depends on how you draw the image on canvas. Post JS code for it or create separate question.

Comment: I tried but still the same problem. The image doesn't fit in the canvas, I can see only like a zoom of my image in the canvas.

Comment: just added some screeshots